# Different time formats in same variable

Tags: powershell, if-statement, active-directory

I am writing a script that is filtering for computer accounts in AD. I want to disable/delete all accounts that are at least inactive for more than 90 days . If they are inactive for at least 90 days they should be disabled and if inactive for more than 180 days they should be deleted

So, I get the dates for disabling and deleting

```
$disbale= (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$delete = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)
```

Now I loop through a given OU and get all accounts that are at least 90 days inactive, therefore I also get those that are inactive for more than 180 days, too.

```
$acc = Get-ADcomputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeSTamp -lt $disable)} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp,Description -SearchBase "OU=Computer,DC=dom,DC=de" -Server dom
```

Then I would put them into a foreach to disbale or delete them

```
foreach ($pc in $acc) {if($pc.LastLogonTimeSTamp -lt $delete){write-host 'delete'} else {write-host 'disable'}}
```

But here I ran into the error that `$pc.LastLogonTimeSTamp` is of type [int64] and is a number of 18 digits and `$delete` is in format time. But why did the same comparison above `LastLogonTimeSTamp -lt $disable` work and now it doenst? How can I work arround this easy?

Comment: `$DeleteFileTime = $delete.ToFileTime()` and then `if($pc.LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $DeleteFileTime)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use Search-ADAccount cmdlet, it's in the same Active Directory module where Get-ADComputer.

```
Search-ADAccount -ComputersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 | where {$_.enabled} | Disable-ADAccount

Search-ADAccount -ComputersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 180.00:00:00 | where {$_.enabled} | Remove-ADComputer
```

As for your exact script you should change it from:

```
 if($pc.LastLogonTimeSTamp -lt $delete)
```

To:

```
if([datetime]::FromFileTime($pc.LastLogonTimeSTamp) -lt $delete)
```

Comment: Hmm good alternative :) thx for that and solving my original question, too ;)

Comment: But with your method I cant access lastLogonTime if I want to first save the accounts to a variable like with: `$acc = Search-ADAccount -ComputersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 -SearchBase "OU=Computer,DC=dom,DC=de" -Server dom`. If I want to start a foreach later like `foreach ($pc in $acc) {$tmpDate=[datetime]::FromFileTime($pc.LastLogonTimeSTamp);if($tmpDate -lt $delete){write-host 'Delete' $pc.name 'lastLogonDate' $tmpDate} else {write-host 'Disable' $pc.name 'lastLogonDate' $tmpDate}}` , lastLogonDate is 01.01.1601 01:00:00. And I still have to use my time variable `$delete`